# git rebase -i HEAD~<n> does not show the commit list or the commands in vi

Tags: git

I am trying to squash come commits but the guides I find on the internet (e.g.[this from Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History)) do not work for me:

```
> git checkout master
> git checkout -b masterBAK
> git log --oneline --graph --decorate -n 4
*   047687e (HEAD) Merged PR 100: Fix pytest using marker
|\  
| * 8ca0695 (origin/correct_bug) add something to pytest
| * 7b247c8 mock some function
|/  
*   5c5c75a (tag: v1.4.0) Merged PR 090: cleanup imports

> git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

I am now expecting to see a list of commits followed by a list of commands as in the link above. Instead I see a blank page in vi, i.e. a cursor where I can write using vim commands followed by tilde symbols. I can quit with ":q". What can I do to see the commits and squash them as described in the guide above?

I don't think it matters, but I use meld in some settings:

```
> git config -l
diff.tool=meld
merge.tool=meld
difftool.prompt=false
..
core.editor=/usr/bin/vi -w   [Solution: faulty -w flag]
```

Comment: You've set your `core.editor` to `/usr/bin/vi -w`. What is the `-w` for? What is the behavior if you remove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> core.editor=/usr/bin/vi -w
> ```

This is the wrong setting.  In particular the `-w` option here is evil.

If your `vi` is one of the more traditional versions, `-w` tells the editor that the *next* argument is the *window size*.  This is expected to be a number, and if it's not a number, odd things may happen.  Git will pass a file name here, which generally won't be a number.  The effect will be to ignore the file name, and open a temporary file.

If your `vi` is a `vim` variant, the `-w` flag means that the *next* argument is a *script output* file.  Again, this consumes the file name that Git wants `vim` to open, so that `vim` opens an empty temporary file instead.  Worse, `vim` now appends stuff that you type into the rebase instruction sheet.

Whatever told you to put `-w` here is wrong.  Remove the `-w`.

Comment: I usually set meld as a diff and merge tool, and I probably switched from nano (which I see recommended with the -w flag) to vim and left the faulty flag

Answer (score 1):

This is my config:

```
diff.tool=vimdiff
merge.tool=vimdiff
core.editor=vim # I think this is the important point
# I don't have difftool.promt
```

And If I do `git rebase -i <commit>` I can see what you are looking for, the option to squash commits.